# How can I Change Netbeans' Highlight Color?

Tags: netbeans

On double click, NetBeans highlights all occurrences of a variable.
How can I change this color? I've played with Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors, but can not find element responsible for this.

[image: netbeans screenshot]

Comment: Maybe the conversation on this page may help you : http://netbeans.org/projects/php/lists/users/archive/2011-06/message/85

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

- Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors
- Syntax
- Select language "Java"
- Change "Mark Occurences" Background

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Java / Netbeans 8.1)

```
Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors
Syntax
Select language "All Languages"
Change "Mark Occurrences" Background
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: I know this is old, but the other answer didn't work for me and this one did. It's not a duplicate, they say to go to different submenus.

Comment: @DavidPostill Agreed with Griffork